# Is Grizzly a web server (NIO based) or a framework

Tags: java, glassfish-3, grizzly

From the official documentation it seems to me that Grizzly is a NIO based framework using which we can build scalable web-servers. However, I also realize that Grizzly is used as a HTTP Connector (front-end) in Glassfish (v3 to be specific).

If Glassfish is using it as a connector, is it custom written using the exposed API's or is there a out of box reference implementation. Can I also run Grizzly as a standalone webserver?

The Glassfish- Grizzly integration documentation is pretty limited on this. Also, if there is a link which explains be diagrammatically the architecture of how Grizzly fit in to the Glassfish architecture (message flow) please share.

Comment: What define a software being a web-server ? Full support for Servlets ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The project Grizzly is NIO framework with an HTTP server module [1] and you don't need Glassfish to run Grizzly HTTP server.

[1] https://grizzly.java.net/httpserverframework.html

Comment: The original question still remains unanswered? Id Grizzly a framework or a web-server? Glassfish has a custom made web-server?

Comment: I wouldn't say Grizzly is a web server, which probably implies Servlets support. Even though Grizzly does have a servlet module, it doesn't implement all the features, so we can't say it's 100% compatible. On the other hand Grizzly has an HttpServer implementation, which is not Servlet-based, but it's fast, light-weight and supports many great features like async processing, NIO streams etc